# In a macOS App that uses KIOSK mode through the Apple Kiosk APIs, can the new NSTouchBar interfere with the KIOSK mode?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I am developing an application that uses the Apple Kiosk APIs, whose documentation is available here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html

to prevent the user from changing frontmost app, force quitting, and using the most common keyboard shortcuts coming from mission control and Accessibility. My application has to be distributed to a number of macbook pro users. Should a user have a new macbook pro with a NSTouchBar, is this opening new ways of gaining control over the system bypassing the Kiosk protections ? is there a programmatic way I can disable totally the NSTouchBar in my app ? if not, is there a programmatic way to detect the current NSTouchBar system settings (like if it shows a particular button) ? Thanks a lot

Comment: That's a good question. I am not sure there is an answer before the units start shipping and people get them and test.